# An error while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile

Tags: flutter

i am trying to debug my flutter project in mac simulator. My mac is mac m1. I am facing error:Error running pod install while doing flutter run. please help

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this issue before but can't recall which solution fixed it.

Try deleting the Pods file under the ios directory. Then in terminal, change your working directory to ios in your project. Write `pod install` then if it doesn't help try running `pod repo update`.

Comment: Running `pod deintegrate` followed by a `pod install` (with perhaps a `pod update` in there) has fixed some CocoaPods errors for me before

Comment: Especially since pod errors started to show more than it used to, don't know if it's relative with the M1 or latest update or just my silliness, I stated to use these more often. Thank you for the addition! @fravolt

Comment: I'm actually using an older i5 Mac Mini for iOS builds, but I feel like they have increased, I guess with more recent versions. I suppose it's also just me adding more dependencies to my app, though